# Changing default ggsave background color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having an issue where a few months ago, the behavior of `ggsave()` seemed to change, defaulting to a transparent background instead of a white background. For instance this code:

```
box_plot <-ggplot(vaccine_data_summary, aes(y = vaccine_uptake, x = region)) +
          geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)

ggsave("box_plot.png", plot = box_plot,  width = 1200, height = 675, units = "px", scale  = 2)
```

Results in a transparent background. To fix this I have been adding the argument for background.

```
ggsave("box_plot.png", plot = box_plot,  width = 1200, height = 675, units = "px", bg = "white", scale  = 2)
```

However, I would prefer to set the default to white again so I wouldn't have to update all of my old code.

Comment: What is your ggplot2 version? There was a fix to 3.5.4 in `ggsave()`

Comment: It is version 3.3.5.

Answer (score 15):

You can override the `ggsave` function.

```
ggsave <- function(..., bg = 'white') ggplot2::ggsave(..., bg = bg)
```

Now when you call `ggsave` function it would use this function with default `bg` value as `'white'`.